# Python - Navigating through Subdirectories that Meet Naming Criteria

Tags: python, csv, datetime, subdirectory, python-os

I am using Python 3.5 to analyze data contained in csv files. These files are contained in a "figs" directory, which is contained in a case directory, which is contained in an overall data directory, e.g.:

> /strm1/serino/DATA/06052009/figs

Or more generally:

> /strm1/serino/DATA/**case_date_in_MMDDYYYY**/figs

The directory I am starting in is '/strm1/serino/DATA/,' and each subdirectory is the month, day, and year of a case I am working with. Each subdirectory contains another subdirectory named 'figs,' and that is the location of each case's csv file. To be exact:

> /strm1/serino/DATA/**case_date_in_MMDDYYYY**/figs/**case_date_in_MMDDYYYY**.csv

So, I would like to start in my DATA directory and go through its subdirectories to find those that have the MMDDYYYY naming. However, some of the case directories may be named with a state abbreviation at the end, like: '06052009_TX.' Therefore, instead of matching the MMDDYYYY naming exactly, it could be something as simple as verifying that the directory name contains any number 1 through 9.

Once I am in the first subdirectory (the case directory) I would like to move into the 'figs' subdirectory. Once there, I want to access the csv file with the same naming convention as the first subdirectory (the case directory). I will fill existing arrays with the data contained in each csv file.

Basically, my question concerns navigating through multiple subdirectories that match a certain naming convention and ultimately accessing the data file at the "end." I was naively playing around with glob, fnmatch, os.listdir, and os.walk, but I could not get anything close enough to working that I feel would be helpful to include. I am not very familiar with those modules. What I can include is what I am going for:

```
    for dirs in data_dir that contain a number:
        go into this directory
        go into 'figs' directory
        read data from the csv file whose name matches its case directory name (or whose name format matches the case directory name format)
```

I have come across related questions, but I have not been able to apply their answers in the way that I would like, especially with nested directories. I really appreciate the help, and let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you going. It uses the `datetime.strptime()` function to attempt to convert each folder name into a valid `datetime` object. If the conversion fails, then you know that the folder name is not in the correct format and can be skipped. It then attempts to parse any CSV file found in the corresponding `fig` folder:

```
from datetime import datetime
import glob
import csv
import os

dirpath, dirnames, filenames = next(os.walk('/strm1/serino/DATA'))

for dirname in dirnames:
    if len(dirname) >= 8:
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(dirname[:8], '%m%d%Y')
            print(dt, dirname)
            csv_folder = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)

            for csv_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(csv_folder, 'figs', '*.csv')):
                with open(csv_file, newline='') as f_input:
                    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

                    for row in csv_input:
                        print(row)

        except ValueError as e:
            pass
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed help with, and seeing it makes sense. I did not realize you could use `datetime.strptime` in that way. I was also unaware of `try` .Thank you so much, and I apologize that it took me a while to respond.

Answer (score 0):

You listed several problems above. Which one are you stuck on? It seems like you already know how to navigate the file storage system using `os.path`. You may not know of the function `os.path.join()` which allows you to manually specify a file path relative to a file as such:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..', 'Data/TrailShelters/'))
```

To break down the above:

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` returns the path of the current file. `'../..'` means: go up two levels in the folder hierarchy. And `Data/TrailShelters/` is the directory I wish to navigate to.

How does this apply to your particular case? Well, you will need to make some adaptations but you can store the `os.path` of the parent directory in a variable. Then you can essentially use a `while sub_dir is not null` loop to iterate through subdirectories. For every subdirectory you will want to examine its `os.path` and extract the particular part of the path you are interested in. Then you can simply use something like: `if 'TN' in subdirectory_name` to determine if it is a subdirectory you are interested in. If so; then update the saved `os.path` of the parent directory by appending the path to the subdirectory. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The answer provided by @Martin Evans below addresses my question more thoroughly. I apologize for any confusion, but navigating through the directories was what I was stuck on. However, you are correct in that I was unaware of `os.path.join()` and that I needed to use that in my code. I appreciate your quick response.